# Liquibase changelog without MD5SUM

Tags: liquibase

I have a database here which is updated using Liquibase. If I understand correctly, Liquibase will apply a changeset and write a line to the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table with the execution date and an MD5 checksum. This way, Liquibase can find out when a changeset (unexpectedly) changes.

However, in this database, many (most) of the `MD5SUM` entries are `NULL`. I have no idea why that should be the case. Is this in any way a normal mode of operation?

When using the Liquibase `status` command, I see many *‘unapplied’* changes. How can Liquibase determine that without the MD5 sum? Or are changesets without MD5 sums considered changed.

Comment: I can not really answer this (because I do not oversee the whole liquibase code as to wether 'NULL' values for checksums are valid values that liquibase knows how to handle). 
But it seems strange to me. There is (I believe) a  pretty central class for creating the checksums: [CheckSum.java](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/change/CheckSum.java). Maybe you want to have a look at it and see if that helps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DATABASECHANGELOG` in question was used by two different programs. This may be questionable, but used to work quite well.

*Until…* the programs started to use different versions of Liquibase with different formats of the `MD5SUM`. Upon detecting this, Liquibase writes `NULL` to the whole column (which is questionable in itself), thereby removing all the checksums for all the other programs. Depending on the order of Liquibase runs, different sets of checksums remained `NULL` in the end.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the same issue and it breaks our deployments.

Comment: No way to cleanly solve this other than using the same Liquibase version everywhere. The “solution” here is to write all the scripts so they have preconditions or are idempotent – I consider this broken, but it kind of works.